# cxf rest versioning by json exception

Tags: json, cxf

this is how expose

```
@POST
@Path("/postPerson/{id}")
@Consumes({"application/com.myapp-v1.0+xml", "application/com.myapp-v1.0+json"})
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Person postPerson(Person person, @PathParam("id") int id) {
    log4j.info("adding person to map   id   : " + id + "  person  : " + person.toString());
    personsMap.put(id, person);
    log4j.info("After size  v1.0 : " + personsMap.size() + " id : " + id);
    return person;
}

@POST
@Path("/postPerson/{id}")
@Consumes({"application/com.myapp-v2.0+xml", "application/com.myapp-v2.0+json"})
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String postPersonv1(Person person, @PathParam("id") int id) {
    log4j.info("Before size  v2.0 : " + personsMap.size() + " id : " + id);      
    personsMap.put(id, person);
    log4j.info("After size  v2.0 : " + personsMap.size() + " id : " + id);
    return "ok";
}
```

XML works fine !!

But When I post Json face this exception :

No message body reader has been found for class server.obj.Person, ContentType: application/com.myapp-v2.0+json
[WARNING] /malamPayroll/cxfDemo/postPerson/1000
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status(ILjava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$ResponseBuilder;
        at javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status(Response.java:921)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMUUD.png)

Comment: please check your dependencies and make sure the right jaxrs jar is on classpath

Comment: I'm using maven 
 <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
<jax.ws.rs>2.1</jax.ws.rs>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, after some experiments I just downgraded version of javax.ws.rs-api from 2.1 to 2.0.1 and exception is gone. still not sure what was causing the exception as in 2.1 sources I couldn't even see status method with string as input parameter.